# Excel : Copy muitple columns to rows based on one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for the most efficient approach to transferring information from three columns to one row, right next to each other depending on the company name.
Consider the following example:

1. I have a 226k data list with product details for several customers (around 30-40k).
2. One customer can have 2 to 50 products, each with a serial number and a product number. Check out the source data pic.

Output required: One row per customer will have all the product data, serial number, and product number next to each other.

Source data

[image: Source data]

desired output
[image: desired output]

I have never used Macro. Can someone please help me find the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Look into `pivot tables` or `Power Query`. If `VBA` is allowed, add the `vba` tag by using `Edit tags` below your post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is pretty tricky, you'll need to play with column numbers to adjust formula:

[image]

The customer list in column F must be typed manually or if you have Excel 365 you may benefit from [UNIQUE Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e). I did it manually.

My formula in cell G2 **is an array formula** (must be entered pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work!

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SI($D$2:$D$14=$F2;CHOOSE(COLUMN()-6-INTEGER((COLUMN()-7)/3)*3;$A$2:$A$14;$B$2:$B$14;$C$2:$C$14);"");MATCH($F2;$D$2:$D$14;0)+INTEGER((COLUMN()-7)/3));"")
```

Drag to right and then drag to down.

My formula uses the value 6 and 7 because my data starts at column G, that means column number 7. So if you put this somewhere else, make sure you change also 7 and 6 values to the proper values!

Anyways, I've uploaded a sample to Gdrive in case you want to check the formulas by yourself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvNUVt0ArzyFK_jsRtZfX1ja2zUgSdhR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true